# Add additional information to a region. iBeacons

Tags: objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I want to be able to add more information, like an array or a string, when I initialize my `CLBeaconRegion` so that I can receive it at my `didRangeBeacons`-method. (**not** major, or minor)

At the moment, it looks like this:

```
_advertRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:_uuid identifier:@"003-002-001"];
```

But I really want to initialize it like this or similar:

```
_advertRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:_uuid identifier:@"003-002-001" setArrayOrSomething:myArray];
```

And also I should obviously be able to take the information from the region like:

```
[region getArray];
```

Of course, it doesn't have to be like that, just that you have an idea, what I "need".

**What I've tried**

- I've tried to set/get it through a `objc_setAssociatedObject`
- I've tried to set it through a `setValue forKey`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you just use a separate NSDictionary instance keyed off the same identifier you use when constructing your CLBeaconRegion.

Like this:

```
// Make this a class variable, or make it part of a singleton object
NSDictionary *beaconRegionData = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

// Here is the data you want to attach to the region
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[[NSMutableArray] alloc] init];

// and here is your region
_advertRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:_uuid identifier:@"003-002-001"];

// attach your data to the NSDictionary instead
[beaconRegionData setValue:myArray forKey:_advertRegion.identifier];

// and you can get it like this    
NSLog(@"Here is my array: %@", [beaconRegionData valueForKey:_advertRegion.identifier]);
```

Comment: As a simplification, CLBeacon conforms to the NSCopying protocol so it can be used directly as key in the dictionary as far as I know.